# Excel to Android XML

Tags: android, excel, android-layout, android-listview

I have a spreadsheet in excel from which I would like to create a small android app for personal use,

Is there a way to convert an excel file in android xml format?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979679/creating-and-writing-to-an-xml-file-in-java-for-android

Comment: this does not solve my question

Comment: You mean that you need to extract xls data into xml?

Comment: I need to recreate the graphics of my excel file on xml for Android